# How to hide multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I want to hide multiple elements when I press a button which get the value of checkboxs, and if the checkbox is checked it's hide.

I have the next code, but it just work with the first element

```
var checkedInputs = $("input:checked");
var test = "";
$.each(checkedInputs, function(i, val) {
    test += val.value+",";
});
test = test.substring(0,(test.length-1));
$("#numRow"+test).hide('slow'); // it should to hide multiple elements, but just work with the first value
```

I also tried with array, but it doen't work too.

```
var numMsj =[1, 2, 4, 22, 44,90, 100];    
$.each(numMsg, function (ind, elem) { 
    $("#numRow"+elem).hide('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The modified solution**

You could just put the hide inside the each loop:

```
var checkedInputs = $("input:checked");
$.each(checkedInputs, function(i, val) {
    test += val.value+",";
    $(this).hide('slow');
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/s8v29/)

---

**The one-liner**

Or if you don't need the `test` variable at all, you can do it is a single line:

```
$("input:checked").hide('slow');
```

[Here is an example on that](http://jsfiddle.net/s8v29/1/)

---

**The problem with your attempts**

Just for reference, the reason your first example doesn't work is because your selector ends up looking like this:

```
$("#numRow1,2,4")
```

Which will select the first element with id `numRow1`, and then tags called `2` and `4`, which won't exist. You would want to create your selector to look like the following:

```
$("#numRow1,#numRow2,#numRow4")
```

However, this is just an example, my alternative methods above are a much better approach.

The problem with your second attempt is simply a typo between `numMsj` and `numMsg`.